# Dovecot: move all e-mail from a sub-mailbox to main INBOX

Tags: dovecot, courier

**Introduction:** I am in the last stage of migrating a very big mail account from a remote courier mail server to a new dovecot server. For this I used  dsync to move the `INBOX` from the old server. Unfortunately there was some GUID conflict so the mail was migrated to a new mailbox (folder) called `INBOX_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c`. The other mailboxes where migrated as they should. The new `INBOX` is empty.

**Question:** So, as the last step, in order to put things back in order, I want to move the mail from `INBOX_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c` to `INBOX`

According to dovecot documentation, this should be doable with the `doveadm move` command, which takes as parameter a search query. Unfortunately neither of these two commands brings any results

```
doveadm move -u myuser INBOX mailbox INBOX_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c ALL
doveadm -D -v search -u myuser mailbox INBOX_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c ALL
```

the only relevant command that I managed to make work was:

```
doveadm -D -v search ALL -u myuser
```

could somebody please advise on that?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there seemed to be a confusion on what exactly the name of the new folder was. So, the name of every sub-folder (mailbox) of INBOX has the prefix INBOX. This can be seen by running

```
 doveadm mailbox list -u
```

which lists the actual names of all existing mailboxes. So the command has to be rewritten:

```
doveadm move -u myuser INBOX mailbox INBOX_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c_c92f64f79f0d1ed01e6d5b314f04886c ALL
```